# Laravel Sort by column in related table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, phpstan

I am asking if there is a way to sort by a second-order table *without* triggering the static analysis.

I have several related tables and I'm trying to sort the results by a related column. For my models, an Encounter belongs to a Site. An Encounter has many Notes. (model definitions below). I have two queries I want to use. First, I want to sort notes by the last name of the encounter (encounters.last_name) and then I want to sort notes by the name of the site (site.name). In SQL, I would do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM notes n 
JOIN encounters e ON n.encounter_id=e.id 
JOIN sites s ON e.site_id=s.id ...

(1) ORDER BY s.name
(2) ORDER BY e.last_name
```

In Laravel, I do the following using [Subquery Ordering](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#subquery-ordering)

```
(1) Note::with(['encounter','encounter.site'])
     ->orderBy(Site::select('name')->whereHas('encounters', 
        fn ($q) => $q->whereColumn('encounter_id', 'encounters.id')));

(2) Note::with(['encounter','encounter.site'])
     ->orderBy(Encounter::select('last_name')
        ->whereColumn('encounter_id', 'encounters.id'))
```

So this works, but it is ugly and it gives me a phpstan error:

```
Parameter #1 $column of method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder<App\Note>::orderBy() expects      
Closure|Illuminate\Contracts\Database\Query\Expression|Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder<App\Note>|Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder|string,
         Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder<App\Encounter> given.
```

Is there a "Laravel" way to have a proper query that doesn't trigger the static analysis?

**What I tried**

One solution I came up with is to use `withAggregate()`, but it only seems to be able to search one table deep. For example, I could do this:

`Note::with(['encounter','encounter.site'])->withAggregate('encounter', 'last_name')->orderBy('encounter_last_name');`

But then this doesn't work:

`Note::with(['encounter','encounter.site'])->withAggregate('encounter.site', 'name')->orderBy('encounter_site_name');`

**What I don't want**

1. I could recreate the SQL statement using `->join()`, but I'm looking to do it in the Laravel way.
2. I could download the notes unsorted and use Laravel's `->sortBy()`, but that is inefficient because of pagination.

**Models**

```
class Encounter extends Model
{
  public function site(): BelongsTo
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Site::class)->withTrashed();
  }
}

class Note extends Model
{
  public function encounter()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Encounter::class);
  }
}
```

Comment: .....`soreBy()`

Comment: Laravel relationships are loaded in a separate query so you can't order by a related model without doing the join yourself. Especially when trying to sort by a 2nd degree relationship

Comment: @mickmackusa - typo, but it expresses my mood if not my syntax

Comment: @apokryfos- Relationships are not always loaded in a separate query. I've shown two methods: `withAggregate()` and Subquery Ordering. My question was how to avoid the static analysis either by better typehinting or by changing the syntax.